# Update WooCommerce shipping costs when selected on basket and checkout pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm unsure if this is a default function of WooCommerce, but I imagine it should be. As of now, it doesn't work.

I add products to the basket and am shown the correct shipping options. I select one, but the total price on the page doesn't change.

If I click through to the checkout, the shipping method resets to the default option (ignoring the one I selected on the basket page). Selecting the correct one again still doesn't update the total price shown on the page.

Checking out and completing the transaction proves that the option chosen **does** get passed to the checkout process and **is** used for the total cost - but I can't figure out why this isn't updated on the previous pages and shown to the user, or why it resets on the checkout page.